# VBA: Using the DateAdd Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet of with identical rows repeated in sequences of three. For example below A represents a row of information.  In column S are dates.  I'd like to change the date in column S in the second row of each sequence to one month after the original date and the third row of each sequence to two months after the original date and do continue this for the entire spreadsheet using a loop and the `DateAdd` function.

Here is the code I have now, but the I'm getting a compile error on the `DateAdd` function (this is my first time using it):

```
Sub DateChange()

Dim r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    With Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
        .Copy
        .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(r, "S"))
    Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 2, Cells(r, "S"))
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: most common issue, if `Cells(r, "S")` on the activesheet( as you are not using fully qualified name) is not a valid date, you will get the error. Check with `IsDate` before adding.  Voted to close as all we can do right now is guess.

Comment: Mat's Mug the error says "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  It is in fact a date. how would you go about qualifying the name cyboashu?  Thank you

Comment: It works for me. Which line is the error on?

Comment: This line, and when debugging the DateAdd function is highlighted: Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Cells(r, "S"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you experience difficulties using the `DataAdd` function then you can bypass it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateChange()

Dim r As Long
Dim dttTemp As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    With ws.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow
        .Copy
        .Resize(2).Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
    dttTemp = ws.Cells(r, "S").Value
    ws.Cells(r + 1, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 1, Day(dttTemp))
    ws.Cells(r + 2, "S").Value = DateSerial(Year(dttTemp), Month(dttTemp) + 2, Day(dttTemp))
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note, that I am also fully qualifying all references (for good coding practice and to avoid errors). This means I am referring to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "S").Value` instead of just `Cells(r, "S")` (as you did). Like this VBA knows in which Excel file to look and at which sheet to look at when searching for cell `S3` (for example). Also, I am telling VBA that I am interested in that cell's `.Value` and not `.Value2` or `.Formula` or anything else.

Let me know if the above helped.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Upon running the code, I got a Error 13, Type Mismatch on this line: dttTemp = ws.Cells(r, "S").Value

Comment: This works, perfectly.  I realized that I needed to get rid of my headers in the first row. I really appreciate the hard work